# Android Bluetooth Communication Between Android App and Java App

Tags: java, android, macos, bluetooth

I want to create an app that passes a string of a command from the Android app to the Java app. I do not know where to start. How could I make something like this where the Android app gives the Java app (running on a Mac or PC) a command and the desktop app does it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time ago, but I actually did something like that.
You can check the project at https://github.com/guillaumyle/BlueRemote/
I suggest you to ignore everything not "Bluetoooth Communication" related, as it is probably not well written. 
Check the blueremote package for the Android part.